# Nothing happens on calling ruby

Tags: macos, mac, ruby

If I type in terminal ruby it just gets stuck, nothing happens.
When I type `which ruby` it outputs `/usr/bin/ruby`.

How do I restore ruby on my mac?

Answer (score 3):

Because `ruby` command tries to execute some script after `ruby` should be `file_name.rb`.

You're trying to execute nothing and ruby hangs.
There are two solutions for your problem:

1. `$ ruby file_name.rb` to execute ruby program
2. `$irb` to open interactive ruby console